# magento 2 query to delete categories

Tags: magento-2.1, database, sql

I want a query to delete one category and all the associate values in all the tables.
In specific i need a query to delete all categories where value=null.

I tried it by code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: the insert lines in Mukesh Prajapati's answer should be updated as follows for newer versions of Magento 2 INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `path`, `position`, `level`, `children_count`, `created_in`, `updated_in`) VALUES ('1', '3', '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '2147483647'), ('2', '3', '1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1/2', '1', '1', '0', '1', '2147483647'); INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `row_id`, `value`) VALUES

Answer (score 3):

Use below queries to delete all categories

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity;

TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_datetime;

TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_decimal;

TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_int;

TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_text;

TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_varchar;

TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_product;

TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_product_index;

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `path`, `position`, `level`, `children_count`) VALUES ('1', '0', '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1', '0', '0', '1'),
('2', '3', '1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1/2', '1', '1', '0');

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES 
('1', '69', '0', '1', '1'),
('2', '46', '0', '2', '1'),
('3', '69', '0', '2', '1');

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES 
('1', '45', '0', '1', 'Root Catalog'),
('2', '45', '0', '2', 'Default Category');

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

DELETE FROM url_rewrite WHERE entity_type = 'category';
```

If you get multiple redirection error while accessing category page after running above query then you need to set default category in default store

[image]

Comment: But i don't want to eliminate them all, only one (or those who  fulfill the condition)

Comment: I tried it (only to try in another magento) and it doesn't create de default root category. Did you know why? maybe because me store_id =1?

Comment: May be. Please check all values which you passing in query @characterError

Comment: It let an emty name to "default category" whatever i change

Answer (score 0):

Thinking outside the box

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;`

`DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity WHERE entity_id = [whatever];`

Then you will have to delete orphan data with queries like this

`DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_category_entity)`

Plus all the other tables mentioned in other answer.

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;`

Once done